# Android unable to include images in an html file that I am attaching in an email intent

Tags: android, html, file, android-intent, attachment

I'll try to explain my problem as best I can.

What I want to do is create a file with an HTML string. This HTML string contains at least one image url. I want this file to then be attached to an email intent.

The email intent successfully gets the attachment, but when I view it, the images are broken and the links associated with the images (ie the images should be clickable) does not work.

Here's what I have:

HTML file `htmlString`:

```
<html>
  ...
  <body>
    ...
    <tr style="background-color:#000000;">
    <td colspan="2" align="center"  > 
    <a href="www.google.com"> 
    <img src="http://full_path_to_image.png"/></a></td>
    </tr>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

`http://full_path_to_image.png` is replaced by an actual image URL.

Creating the html file from string:

```
String fileName = "fileName.html";
File theFile = null;
    try {
        theFile = new File(getActivity().getExternalCacheDir(), fileName);
        stringToFile(htmlString,theFile.getAbsoluteFile());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error creating temporary file!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Attaching to email:

```
ArrayList<Uri> filesToAttach = new ArrayList<Uri>();
filesToAttach.add(Uri.fromFile(theFile));
```

I then set up the intent, attach the files, and everything works as it should. However, if I open the attachment, the images appear to be broken. If I click on the broken image, I get a page on the browser with the error message:

```
The webpage at content://com.android.htmlfileprovider/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.test.testApplication/cache/www.google.com could not be loaded because: 

net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

I am not sure how to both get my images to work and how to get the links to function correctly.

Comment: You're right. However, that's not the url that I have in my HTML string. I assume Android's browser is attaching that prefix, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: It'd be nice to get the images to load from web, but I will give this a try.

Comment: I was able to fix my second problem about the link not working: I simply had to prefix with `http://`. Setting the image into the assets folder and referencing as a relative path didn't seem to work.

Comment: If you send a html file and two image files as attachment then the receiver has first to save those three attachments to probably the downloads folder. After that a browser can open the html file. For the images to become visible the src attribute in the img tag should be a relative one. In this case just the image file name. Is this your scenario?

Comment: I'd prefer the images come from the web. I notice if I open the html attachment from a PC that the images load fine, but form an Android device they are broken. This is when using the url for the image rather than a relative path to a local file. If I use the relative path, the image is broken on both PC and Android device.